# Can I make a POJO out of this json response?

Tags: json, kotlin, post, retrofit

server is giving me json object as a response to my post request that looks like this

```
{"fname":"test"}{"fileToUpload":{"name":"sample.pdf","type":"application\/pdf","tmp_name":"\/tmp\/phpnZClmI","error":0,"size":3028}}
```

However, I am getting errors that json hasn't been fully consumed. My model classes look like this:

```
data class FileRoot (
    val fname: String,
    val fileToUpload: FileToUpload
        )
data class FileToUpload (
        val name:String,
        val type:String,
        val tmp_name:String,
        val error:Int,
        val size:Int
)
```

This is how my post response looks like:

```
suspend fun pushPost(
            @Body fileToPost: FileToPost
    ):Response<List<FileRoot>>
```

Is the problem my server response? I just want to make a single object out of these two json files, I read that I just put them in the same model class, but that doesn't seem to work. Could the problem be incorrect json syntax from the server?
Please help, thank you.

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: @Alex.T com.google.gson.JsonIOException: JSON document was not fully consumed.

Comment: Server response is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @МихаилНафталь is right, `fileToUpload` is not part of the same object as `fname`, if you take the json that you posted and format it, you'll see that there are 2 different objects.

Comment: @МихаилНафталь thank you I requested a different response. Cheers